# Navigate back to specific view controller class

Tags: swift5

```
let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers as! [FirstViewController];

        for aViewController in YourViewController {
            if(aViewController is YourViewController){
                self.navigationController!.popToViewController(aViewController, animated: true);
            }
}
```

Above code sets specific class to pop in navigation controller

Comment: Can you please clearly explain the question that you would like people to answer?

Answer (score 0):

// pops to the 3rd controller in the stack

```
navigationController!.popToViewController(navigationController!.viewControllers[2], animated: false)
```